# Angular ngx-treeview Styling

Tags: angular, ngx-treeview

I am a bit new to Angular and HTML.
I am using ngx-treeview library to my Angular project and I want to style it, but I don't know how.
If someone could help me, I would appreciate it.
I want to move arrow on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-nowrap {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```